# Linking gcc to gcc-6 using brew

Tags: gcc, clang, homebrew, symlink

I installed gcc-6 using `brew install gcc`

This installed gcc-6 in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.3.0_1/bin/gcc-6`

However, the command `ggc -v` returns:

`Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

which is still the default "gcc" from xcode, which is really clang. So i need to link gcc to gcc-6. I have tried `brew link gcc`. Any input is appreciated!

edit: `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` if it helps

Comment: `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved!

added `usr/local/bin` to the front of $PATH, then `ln -s gcc-6 gcc`